# Kivy window shows nothing

Tags: python, kivy

The kivy window shows nothing

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Name: '))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


class MyApp(App):
    def biuld(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

There's my pip list, im using python 3.7.8:

- certifi             2020.6.20
- chardet             3.0.4
- docutils            0.16
- idna                2.10
- Kivy                1.11.1
- kivy-deps.angle     0.2.0
- kivy-deps.glew      0.2.0
- kivy-deps.gstreamer 0.2.0
- kivy-deps.sdl2      0.2.0
- Kivy-Garden         0.1.4
- pip                 20.1.1
- Pygments            2.6.1
- pypiwin32           223
- pywin32             228
- requests            2.24.0
- setuptools          47.1.0
- urllib3             1.25.9

Comment: I don't know kivy, but I do notice that your `MyApp` class implements / overrides a `biuld` method, which looks like a typo to me, could that be your issue? What error do you get?

Also, the full list of python requirements probably isn't relevant to your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html):

> To initialize your app with a widget tree, override the build() method in your app class and return the widget tree you constructed.

In short, you're `build` method has a typo (`def biuld`). Here's an updated version that should work for you:

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Name: '))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def biuld(self):
```

You misspelled build.